# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0 .NET Standard and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, json.net, .net-standard

We have a solution with two projects:

1. A desktop App using WPF (.NET 4.6)
2. A class Library (.NET Standard) that connects to remote REST API.

We are using NewtonSoft JSON 13.0.0.1 (installed via NuGet) in the class library project. We referenced the class library project in the WPF project. Whenever we call a method in the library project from WPF application, we get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0... could not find the file...
```

I am clueless as to why 13.0.0.0 is being searched when 13.0.0.1 version is installed, I even tried with the 12.x. version, it also gives the same error only searching for 12.0.0.0 version.

Is this a WPF .NET and Libary .NET Stanard conflict issue? How to resolve this?

[image: Screenshot of the error in Visual Studio]

Comment: Did you try adding the Nuget to the WPF project?

Comment: Have you already added the nuget package to the wpf app? Check if you need to upgrade it's version in nuget manager.